# Android - update widget text

Tags: android, widget

i have 2 questions about widgets update

- I have 2 buttons and i need to change one button text when i press the other one, how can i do this?
- The first time i open the widget it calls the onUpdate method, but it never calls it again. I need to update the widget every 2 seconds and i have this line in the xml.

  android:updatePeriodMillis="2000"

Do i need a service or should it works just with the updatePeriodMillis tag?

- onUpdate method

  ```
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.newswidget);

  Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetalleConsulta.class);
  intent.putExtra(DetalleConsulta.CONSULTA_ID_NAME, "3");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
  views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btNews, pendingIntent);

  /* Inicializa variables para llamar el controlador */
  this.imei = ((TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
  this.controlador = new Controlador(this.imei);

  try {
      this.respuestas = this.controlador.recuperarNuevasRespuestas();

      if(this.respuestas != null && this.respuestas.size() > 0){
          Iterator<Consulta> iterRespuestas = this.respuestas.iterator();
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.btNews, ((Consulta)iterRespuestas.next()).getRespuesta());
      }
  } catch (PersistenciaException e) {
      //TODO manejar error
  }

  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
  ```

thx a lot!!!

Comment: do you have the intent of your widget defined in your Manifest.xml file??? 
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
post your code!

Comment: yes, i have this code in the manifest

<receiver android:name="co.edu.uniandes.moosas.lib.widget.news.NewsWidget">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/newswidget"/>
  </receiver>

Comment: Hola David, Do u have in your main activity that starts the widget?
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" /></intent-filter> 
could you post your Android Manifest.xml?

Comment: hi jorge, the problem seems to be that in 1.6 the minimun to update is 30 min. Do you know how to update the text in a button when i press another button???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- about the first question i found a great example about handle widget events:

[Handling User Interaction with Android App Widgets](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3837531_1/Handling-User-Interaction-with-Android-App-Widgets.htm)

- about the second one i was reading on the web and i found that in android 1.6 the minimun time to update the widget is 30 min.

I tried it and it works.

i hope this help others!!!

Answer (score 0):

**yes that changed since donut(1.6) to avoid your battery will be consumed shortly.**

Hey David the next time try to put your other question in different thread to be accord with stackoverflow.com =)

to update the text from another button...

```
 final    Button btn1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
   final Button btn2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button02);

   btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btn2.setText("Button1 changed your text!");
            }           
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the advive, next time i'll make the questions in different threads. 
About the answer i want to do this but in my application widget, the answer is in the link i post in my own answer... thx...